# Intermingling attr_accessor and an initialize method in one class

Tags: ruby, initialization, accessor

I see code like:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

I understand this allows me to do things like `person = Person.new` and to use `@name` elsewhere in my class like other methods. Then, I saw code like:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name
end

...

person = Person.new
person.name = "David"
```

I'm just at a loss with these two methods mesh. What are the particular uses of `def initialize(name)`? I suppose `attr_accessor` allows me to read and write. That implies they are two separate methods. Yes? Want clarifications on `def initialize` and `attr_accessor` and how they mesh.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`initialize` and `attr_accessor` have nothing to do with each other. `attr_accessor :name` creates a couple of methods:

```
def name
  @name
end

def name=(val)
  @name = val
end
```

If you want to set name upon object creation, you can do it in the initializer:

```
def initialize(name)
  @name = name
  # or
  # self.name = name
end
```

But you don't have to do that. You can set name later, after creation.

```
p = Person.new
p.name = "David"
puts p.name # >> "David"
```

Comment: I see. The initializer method is used as a way to initialize values when creating objects. It isn't necessary, but if the object has a lot of attributes it makes sense to be able to do it all at once rather than spend time and set all the attributes later, after creation. Yes?

Comment: @David Sort of. The caveat is that if the object has a lot of attributes the initializer rapidly becomes a useless mess of ordered parameters. That's why (a) we now have named parameters, and/or (b) you can use maps to increase readability at the point of construction.

Comment: @DaveNewton do you have a very short example of both? I think I know what you mean but want to be sure. When you say we now have named parameters, do you imply we used to not? How else would we have managed to say "I want to take in this and that parameter" when defining the method?

Comment: @David "Named parameters" refer to names usable on the *calling* side, not on the method declaration side, where obviously they have names in Ruby, and always have AFAIK. For a *really* rough overview see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/ce2e1857eebb616dcc21).

Answer (score 21):

Here is the answer you are looking for [`Classes and methods`](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/ruby/chp_04/classes.html). Read it carefully.

Here is a good documentation from the link:

***Classes and methods***

Now we are ready to create our very own Address class. Let's start simple. Let's start with an address that only contains the "street" field.

This is how you define a class:

```
class Address
    def initialize(street)  
        @street = street 
    end
end
```

Let's go through this:

- The class keyword defines a class.
- By defining a method inside this class, we are associating it with this class.
- The initialize method is what actually constructs the data structure. Every class must contain an initialize method.

@street is an object variable. Similar to the keys of a hash. The @ sign distinguishes @street as an object variable. Every time you create an object of the class Address, this object will contain a @street variable.

Let's use this class to create an address object.

```
address = Addres.new("23 St George St.")
```

That's it. address is now an object of the class Address
Reading the data in an object

Suppose that we want to read the data in the address object. To do this, we need to write a method that returns this data:

```
class Address
    def initialize(street)   
        @street = street 
    end

    # Just return @street
    def street
        @street
    end
end
```

Now the method Address#street lets you read the street of the address. In irb:

```
>> address.street 
=> "23 St George St."
```

A property of an object, which is visible outside, is called an attribute. In this case, street is is an attribute. In particular, it is a readable attribute. Because this kind of attribute is very common, Ruby offers you a shortcut through the attr_reader keyword:

```
class Address
    attr_reader :street
    def initialize(street)   
        @street = street 
    end
end
```

***Changing the data in an object***

We can also define a method to change the data in an object.

```
class Address
    attr_reader :street
    def initialize(street)  
        @street = street 
    end
    def street=(street)
        @street = street
    end
end
```

Ruby is pretty smart in its use of the street= method:

```
address.street = "45 Main St."
```

Notice that you can put spaces betten street and =. Now that we can change the address data, we can simplify the initialize method, and have it simply default the street to the empty string "".

```
class Address
    attr_reader :street
    def initialize
        @street = ""
    end
    def street=(street)
        @street = street  
    end
end

address = Address.new
address.street = "23 St George St."
```

This might not seem like much of a simplification, but when we add the city, state and zip fields, and more methods this will make the class definition a bit simpler.

Now, street is also a writable attribute. As before, you can declare it as such with attr_writer:

```
class Address
    attr_reader :street
    attr_writer :street  
    def initialize
        @street = ""
    end
end
```

***Accessing data***

Very often, you have attributes that are both readable and writable attributes. Ruby lets you lump these together with attr_accessor. I guess these would be called "accessible attributes", but I have never seen them be called that.

```
class Address
    attr_accessor :street  
    def initialize
        @street = ""
    end
end
```

With this knowledge, it is now easy to define the entire addressbook structure. As it turns out, attr_accessor and friends all accept multiple arguments.

```
class Address
    attr_accessor :street, :city, :state, :zip  
    def initialize
        @street = @city = @state = @zip = ""
    end
end
```

Comment: Please include actual content in the answer instead of just giving a link. Link-only answers are frowned on, both because (a) the answers don't stand on their own, and (b) if the link goes down it's worse than useless.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am done. Any more I have to add? please comment.

Comment: IMO it's far too long an answer, but that's just me--it's not link-only, which was my concern.

Comment: @Priti I notice in the very last code snippet, we have `def initialize; @street = @city = @state = @zip = ""` Essentially what you've done in this code snippet is when we initialize an address, it's going to have nothing, and I'll have to write in the different attributes, yes? I'm trying to confirm that `address = Address.new("street", "city", "state", "zip")` would not be valid because those aren't in the parameter list for the `initialize` method

Comment: @David The answer I posted is all about the `initialize` and `getter` and `setter` method. Read carefully you will get the answers you are looking for, this two is very simple.

Answer (score 6):

I think you consider `initialize` as a constructor. To be precise, it is not. The default constructor is the `new` method on the class, and `initialize` is called by that method. If you do not define `initialize`, you can still create an object with `new` because `initialize` is not the constructor itself. In that case, the default `initialize` does nothing. If you do define `initialize`, then that is called right after the object creation.

The statement `@foo = ...` and `attr_accessor :foo` are different. The former assigns a value to the instance variable `@foo`, whereas the latter lets you access `@foo`  via methods `foo` and `foo=`. Without the latter, you can still access `@foo` by directly describing so.

Comment: Would it be correct to consider ''attr_accessor'' as a constructor in the same way that we consider could ``initialize`` to be one (acts like but isn't)? That is does the actual constructor ``new`` also call ``attr_accessor`` which then creates getters and setters or is something else going on?

Answer (score -2):

Unlike C++,Java instance variables in Ruby are **private** by default(partially as they can be accessed by using a.instance_variable_get :@x)

eg:

```
  class Dda
    def initialize task
        @task = task
        @done = false
    end
  end
item = Dda.new "Jogging" # This would call the initializer and task = Jogging would
be set for item
item.task # would give error as their is no function named task to access the instance
variable.
```

Although we have set the value to item but we won't be able to do anything with it as instace variables are private in ruby.
code for getter:

```
def task
  @task
end
#for getter
def task=task
   @task = task
end
```

Using getter would ensure that item.task  returns it's value
And using setter gives us the flexibility to provide values to instance variables at any time.