# How to Initialize Class Arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to create an empty array as a class instance variable in Ruby. However, my current method does not seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
class Something 
    @something = []
    def dosomething
        s = 5
        @something << s
    end
end
```

When I call the function, it gives me an undefined method traceback.
However, if I do something similar with class variables, i.e.:

```
class Something
    @@something = []
    def dosomething
        s = 5
        @@something << s
    end
end
```

This works perfectly.

I know I can use the initialize method to actually create an empty list for @something, but is there another way of doing this without using the initialize method? And why does this work for class variables?

EDIT: Fixed typo

Comment: *"without using the initialize method"* - is there any reason to avoid `initialize`?

Comment: Your question is clear that you want to initialize a class instance variable, not an instance variable, not a class variable. Yet you assigned the greenie to an answer that makes no reference to class instance variables. Why? btw, some Rubiests *never* use class variables, always opting for class instance variables instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use initialize as a constructor as below code and is there any reason why not to use initialize/constructor. And please fix a typo error in class definition `Class Something` to `class Something` no camel case or first letter capitalize while in class

```
class Something 
      def initialize
        @something = Array.new
      end
      def dosomething
        s = 5
        @something << s
      end
    end
```

class variable `@@` are available to the whole class scope. so they are working in the code and if you want to use instance variable @ you need to initialize it as above. The instance variable is share with instance/objects of a class

for more details visit the link [Ruby initialize method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655915/intermingling-attr-accessor-and-an-initialize-method-in-one-class)

Comment: Generally `[]` is preferable to `Array.new` unless you're doing something that involves passing arguments to `new` like `Array.new(10)`.

Comment: Yes, and in above case there was no use of argument sending :) so i prefer Array.new..

Comment: That's your personal preference, but the majority of Ruby style guides frown on it as needless clutter.

Comment: Class variables are *not* global variables.  Global variables are available to any object in the Ruby object space.  @@ variables are available only to the class in which they are defined, and their subclasses.

Comment: Yes, Thank you Keith Bennet Updated

Comment: Where's the class instance variable?

Comment: I did not mention in code but tried to define the questioner's code

Answer (score 2):

At first you have a typo. Change `Class`to `class`. Next I suggest to use the initialize method. While creating a new object this is the perfect place to initialize instance variables.

```
class Something
  @@my_class_variable = [1]

  def initialize
    @something = []
  end

  def dosomething
    s = 5
    @something << s
  end

  def self.get_my_class_variable
    @@my_class_variable
  end
end
```

Your script will be read and executed from top to bottom and after this, 
you can access the class `Something`. While the parser reads your script/class/module you can define class variables (@@), execute mixins and extend the class with other modules. This is why you can define a class variable, but you can not define an instance variable. Because actually you have no instance object from your class. You only have a class object. In ruby everything is an object. And your class object has a defined class variable now:

```
Something.get_my_class_variable
# => [1]
```

Now you can create an instance from your class. With `Something.new` the initialize method will be invoked and your instance variable will be defined.

```
something = Something.new
something.dosomething
# => [5]
```

Later, if you are familar with this you can define getter and setter methods with `attr_reader`, `attr_writer` and `attr_accessor` for instance objects or  `cattr_reader`, `cattr_writer` and `cattr_accessor` for class objects. For example:

```
class Something
  attr_reader :my_something

  def initialize
    @my_something = []
  end

  def dosomething
    s = 5
    @my_something << s
  end
end

something = Something.new
something.my_something
# => []
something.dosomething
# => [5]
something.my_something
# => [5]
```

Comment: Alright thanks for that. 

Do you know why my code works for class variables though?

Comment: @Shwunky Because that's how class variables work. Class variables are intended to be used in the class context (rather than an instance context) and so Ruby provides a way for you to initialize them when you create a class.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in trying to access `@something` in your instance method is that, in the scope of instance methods, `@` variables refer to instance variables, and your `@something` is a *class* instance variable.

`@` variables are instance variables of the instance that is `self` when they are created.  When `@something` was created, `self` was the class `Something`, not an *instance* of Something, which would be the case inside an instance method.

How then to access a class instance variable in an instance method?  Like regular instance variables, this must be done via a method, as in `attr_accessor`.  One way to do this is to use `class << self` to tell the Ruby interpreter that the enclosed code should be evaluated with the class (and not the instance) as self:

```
class C

  @foo = 'hello'

  class << self
    attr_accessor :foo  # this will be a class method
  end

  def test_foo  # this is, of course, an instance method
    puts self.class.foo  # or puts C.foo
  end
end
```

We can show that this works in irb:

```
2.3.0 :005 > C.foo
 => "hello"
2.3.0 :006 > C.new.test_foo
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly created a class instance variable, `@something`, and initialized it to an empty array. There are two ways for instances to obtain or change the value of that variable. One is to use the methods [Object#instance_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) and [Object#instance_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) (invoked on the class):

```
class Something
  @something = [] 
  def dosomething
    s = 5
    self.class.instance_variable_get(:@something) << s
  end
end

sthg = Something.new
sthg.dosomething     

Something.instance_variable_get(:@something)
   #=> 5
```

The other way is to create an accessor for the variable. There are several ways to do that. My preference is the following:

```
Something.singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, :something)
Something.something #=> [5]
```

In your `dosomething` method you would write:

```
self.class.something << s
```